# Android, getLastLocation() from IntentService

Tags: android, service, get, location, intentservice

I have an IntentService wich should get the user location, and depending of it, download some data from internet. And the problem im facing is that many times, the service is finnished before the method onConnected() gets called. So the Location is null. It doesnt happen all the times, but very often.

I could do it somehow different (like an asynctask), but the IntentService can be called either from an activity (when the user presses a button) or with an AlarmManager (periodically). So i dont know another way to do it. Well, i could create an asynctask that first gets the location, and after, launches the IntentService. And do something different when the Service is called from the AlarmManager. But i would have to create different code for, at the end, do the same thing.

So my question is, is there any way to sort it out, keeping the IntentService? Or is there another better way to do it?

Thanks in adv.

Ps: Ive followed the guide from Android Developers:

https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use an `IntentService` - use a regular `Service` and:

1. Start listening for location when your Service is started
2. When you get a location back, start a background thread to download your data (and stop location updates if you only want a single location)
3. Call [stopSelf](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf%28%29) once your download is complete to stop the service

Comment: So, if i understand it correctly, i create a service wich is allways listening for locations. So this service should have allways a valid (not null) location. Then i would keep my IntentService, but with a valid Location object already prepared when it starts. Is it correct? Btw, would it drain the battery?

Comment: All an IntentService does (if you look at the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java)) is create a separate processing thread and stop the service when that thread completes. My suggestion was to control the lifecycle yourself - waiting until you have a location before starting the processing thread and stopping the service upon completion. You'd still not want to listen to location updates all the time (as that would drain the battery).

Comment: And how would i control the lifecycle myself?

Comment: That's what stopSelf is for - for stopping the service when you are done processing.

Comment: I dont use stopSelf. I connect the LocationClient in onCreate. And do all the background work in onHandleIntent. Then when all the work is done in onHandleIntent, sometimes onConnected has not been called.

Comment: Right, that's an `IntentService` - it calls `stopSelf` immediately upon `onHandleIntent` finishing (no matter if `onConnected` is called or not). I'm suggesting to **not use `IntentService`** as that default behavior is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hi what I recommend in your case... is create a service that will be updating the current location... and you charge your var´s with the coordinates... let me show you an example

first you declare the variables

```
public class MyService extends Service{
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;
String sLat;
String sLong;
```

and then on your on locationChange method you charge sLat and sLong

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        sLat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
        sLong = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
```

so sLat and sLong they are going to have the location and they will be available whenever you want...

regards...